# Google chrome prints extra page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm currently in the process of making a website (wordpress) print-friendly using css and on certain pages when printing on A4 it leaves a fully blank last page (see here for an example: http://takana.co.nz/?page_id=25).

When simulating a print using Google Chrome's Developer Tools and the option "Emulate CSS media" I can't find anything that would be adding any more whitespace below the end of the content.

The immediate conclusion is that something's adding whitespace beyond the footer text however I can't inspect element on a printed page to find it.

What is causing the extra page when using print preview on chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems issue is with the `padding`. Try to adjust `padding` for `.entry-wrap` for media print.

May be something like below

```
@media print {
 .entry-wrap {
   padding: 25px; /* adjust it accordingly */
 }
}
```

Hope this will help you someway (y).

Answer (score 11):

Use Following Code in css

```
 @media print {
     html, body {
        border: 1px solid white;
        height: 99%;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        page-break-before: avoid;
     }
}
```

See The Preview After Adding Css ;

[image]

Comment: somehow it works for me after adding the border. not sure why though

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this fairly heavy-handed solution worked:

```
@media print {
     html, body {
        height: 99%;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
}
```

Basically, you can simply force everything after the first page to be hidden. Obviously you want to be pretty sure that you're not losing anything valuable.

Comment: Just overflow:hidden on html and body @media print fixed it for me (after trying a million other things)

Answer (score 2):

I try to print and it was one page, you can try add print break after- before avoid on i.e footer

```
@media print {
    footer {page-break-after: avoid;}
}
```

Comment: The footer is set to not print at all though.. I'll try placing that in a few places: `@media print footer {display: none;}`

Comment: Actually this is some solution strip all extra fancy elements, so people save ink. When i do it i just leave H1 and then content because that people need.